# how to fix "Can not find module 'dotenv'" in google cloud app engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I am new in google cloud app engine. I am trying to deploy a node app to GCP. But the following error is showing:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'
2021-02-14 06:07:04 backend[20210214t120450]  Require stack:
2021-02-14 06:07:04 backend[20210214t120450]  - /workspace/app.js
2021-02-14 06:07:04 backend[20210214t120450]      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
2021-02-14 06:07:04 backend[20210214t120450]      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
2021-02-14 06:07:04 backend[20210214t120450]      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
2021-02-14 06:07:04 backend[20210214t120450]      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2021-02-14 06:07:04 backend[20210214t120450]      at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/app.js:5:1)
2021-02-14 06:07:04 backend[20210214t120450]      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
2021-02-14 06:07:04 backend[20210214t120450]      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
2021-02-14 06:07:04 backend[20210214t120450]      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
2021-02-14 06:07:04 backend[20210214t120450]      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
2021-02-14 06:07:04 backend[20210214t120450]      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {
2021-02-14 06:07:04 backend[20210214t120450]    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-02-14 06:07:04 backend[20210214t120450]    requireStack: [ '/workspace/app.js' ]
2021-02-14 06:07:04 backend[20210214t120450]  }
```

My app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const env = require("./config/config");
const uri = `${env.MONGO_CONN_URL}`;
const PORT = env.PORT;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(fileUpload());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
   res.send("Hello from db, it's working");
});

// connect to db
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

client.connect((err) => {
   const applicantsCollection = client.db(`${env.DB_NAME}`).collection("applicants");

   // Upload Endpoint
   app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
      const file = req.files.file;
      const name = req.body.name;
      const email = req.body.email;
      const work = req.body.work;

      if (req.files === null) {
         return res.status(400).json({ msg: "No file uploaded" });
      }

      applicantsCollection.insertOne({ name, email, work, file }).then((result) => {
         res.send(result.insertedCount > 0);
         console.log(result);
      });
   });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
   console.log(`Server running on ${PORT}`);
});
```

My config.js:

```
require("dotenv").config();

const env = {
   PORT: process.env.PORT,
   MONGO_CONN_URL: process.env.MONGO_CONN_URL,
   DB_NAME: process.env.DB_NAME,
};

module.exports = env;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "audify-tech-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "javascript"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
  }
}
```

I have also tried out this way by changing dev property in package.json:

```
{
  "name": "audify-tech-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon -r dotenv/config app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "javascript"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
  }
}
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs12
instance_class: B1

service: backend

basic_scaling:
   max_instances: 1

env_variables:
   PORT: 8080
   MONGO_CONN_URL: mongodb connection string
   DB_NAME: "db"
   GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID: "abcd-website"
```

But the error remains same in google cloud that can't find module "dotenv". I have also tried by reinstalling dotenv. But it doesn't work. All the possible ways I have tried is working well in local machine.

Comment: If its working locally, the problem is probably in app engine configuration. Can you add `app.yaml`?

Comment: check it, I have added app.yaml

Comment: I have tried to replicate this, but I don't get this error. Does it appeared during deploy? (running `gcloud app deploy`)

Comment: no, after deployment

Comment: How do you run it locally?

Answer (score 1):

Move `dotenv` from devDependencies to dependencies

Comment: It worked for me, thank you very much man, you deserve a beer. :D